# How to configure logbook logging in feign via ApacheHttpClient?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign, logbook

I have a rest project on spring-boot (v. 2.2.2.RELEASE) using spring cloud openfeign (v. Hoxton.SR7) and logging requests and responses via org.zalando.logbook (v. 2.3.0). Logbook succesfully log requests and responses via RestController **into** my application, but doesn't log requests and responses **from** my app to another services.
So, for logging I want to add logbook interceptors (`org.zalando.logbook.httpclient.LogbookHttpRequestInterceptor` and `org.zalando.logbook.httpclient.LogbookHttpResponseInterceptor`) into `HttpClient` in feign config `org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.clientconfig.HttpClientFeignConfiguration` for logging, but I can't do it because of method `org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.clientconfig.HttpClientFeignConfiguration#createClient` is **private** and no one method for customization `HttpClient`.

Is there any way to customize Feign httpClient or another way to add logging via logbook?

Comment: Have you made sure to set you Feign logging to FULL and your project logging level to Debug for the feign package?  more info via: https://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/spring-cloud.html#_feign_logging

Comment: @JoeyHolloway I've already tried this, it works, but in my opinion it's another way - another format and it seems not all data that provides by logbook. For logging I can change logging level of `org.apache.http.wire` or `org.apache.http` or `org.springframework.web.filter.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter` to DEBUG but I think it's another way. I want to use logbook like in all my project (Maybe I want too much:)). In another case (not just logging) I guess it will be useful to add custom interceptors for Feign HttpClient.